# Add Secured Large Document in form of Word or PDF or Epub format on php website

Tags: php, security, pdf, ms-word, epub

We are planning to add some of the publications on our website Oshopindia.com.

We want to make these documents Online Readable Only.

We donot want anyone to copy/cut/screenshot or copy the publication in any manner. As the publication is copy righted by supplier, we cannot allow anyone to replicate or reproduce the same. How can we add large publication document online in form of PDF or Epub format or any other format and make it secure? Our Website is PHP based.

Comment: You can't stop people from copying it.  You can hinder them in ways such as capturing the right click of the mouse, or adding watermarks to the content.  If you put it out there people can copy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you put your data online it's open to be copied.  The only way to make it so that people can't copy it is to not put it online.  You can hinder them from copying it, but you can't stop them.  Large online publishers can't even do this.  Look at an Amazon book preview.  They use images, which makes it harder to copy the text, but you can still copy the image.

Answer (score 0):

Simply said you can not do this. If the content can be viewed people can make screenshots. If you want it to be secure don't publish it.

options:

- Dont publish
- Show an image so people can not copy text and use a good copyright

Comment: Hi,these are copy righted publications. Is it possible to ban screen shots in any form? We thought of preventing screenshot but any one would go to view source and directly go to image url and copy it.

Comment: Please suggest us best options. As these are large publications, i.e. supplier's monthly magazines and newsletters, we cannot allow anyone to copy or save them..

Comment: @Oshopindia.com If your requirement is to not let people copy it then your ONLY option is to not put it on the web

Comment: is it possible to convert the documents in flash and add them on site?

Comment: @Boundless :- The publications are meant for people. But are copy righted just like books. If we make them open, we shall be sued due to copy right norms.

Comment: Sure, it's even possible to convert them to a video and stream them, but the point is people will still be able to copy it if they want.  You can make it harder for them, but you can't stop them.

Comment: @Boundless :- True..Can we make them to Flash and upload it? Can flash file be copied or reproduced or replicated?

Comment: @Oshopindia.com Flash is very insecure.  You can debug flash on the web. You can also take screen shots.

Comment: @Boundless :- Ok.. What are the other options? So what do Online Magazine publishers use to prevent copy?